# Outputting null_data_source output as plain maps instead of array of maps in terraform

Tags: terraform

```
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.null v2.0.0

    
variable "vpc1" {
  type = "list"

  default = [
    "name1:ip1:az1:dedicated",
    "name2:ip2:az2:dedicated",
  ]
}

variable vpc2 {
  type = "list"

  default = [
    "foo:10.1:east:yes",
    "bar:10.2:west:no",
  ]
}

data "null_data_source" "values" {
  count = "${length(var.vpc1)}"

  inputs = "${
          map (

                "${element(split(":",var.vpc1[count.index]),0)}",
               "${element(split(":", var.vpc2[count.index]),0)}"
              )
        }"
}

output "mappings" {
  value = "${data.null_data_source.values.*.outputs}"
}
```

How to get the desired output , What am i missing

Answer (score 1):

You need function of `flatten()`

```
  output  "mappings" {
    value = "${flatten(data.null_data_source.values.*.outputs)}"
  }
```

And there is easy way to get what you need with function `concat()`

```
variable "vpc1" {
  type = "list"

  default = [
    "name1:ip1:az1:dedicated",
    "name2:ip2:az2:dedicated",
  ]
}

variable vpc2 {
  type = "list"

  default = [
    "foo:10.1:east:yes",
    "bar:10.2:west:no",
  ]
}

output "mappings" {
  value = "${flatten(concat(var.vpc1, var.vpc2))}"
}
```

Here is the output

```
$ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

mappings = [
    name1:ip1:az1:dedicated,
    name2:ip2:az2:dedicated,
    foo:10.1:east:yes,
    bar:10.2:west:no
]
```

reference:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#flatten-list-of-lists-

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#concat-list1-list2-

Comment: Thank you .. Tried the flatten option  for the first case         
 output  "mappings" {
    value = "${flatten(concat(data.null_data_source.values.*.outputs))}"  .           Did not work . Prints in the same manner as nested lists                     Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

mappings = [
    {
        name1 = foo
    },
    {
        name2 = bar
    }
]

Comment: When i filter out the first fields (name1,name2)  from var.vpc1 and the corresponding values from (foo,bar) from var.vpc2 it puts it in a array with curly braces which is not what i want , flatten works only if they are within square brackets

Comment: Seems the sample here is different to the file you are testing. I can't guess your original terraform files. If you put the real one, we should be fine to fix